# Flutter: Implementing search in infinite scroll list issue

Tags: flutter, dart

**I'm trying** to implement searching inside an **infinite list pagination** whether locally or by query in the API, but there's an issue whenever I use any type of *FormField* to type, the widget rebuilds and `pagingController` gets disposed then I get an error.

I'm using a stateful widget and a `pagingController` for the pagination, and dispose of it in the dispose method.

Is there a solution or has anyone encountered this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use
https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination

this will make your search and pagination super-easy.

if you want to do it manually

Check flutter official sample which uses provider

https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/main/infinite_list

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this package supports searching, I should read docs more thoroughly.